# sending function throw `spread operator` not works but state value added

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am passing a function and a state value throw `spread` operator. the `state` value update in the `html`. but while click on `button` function not calling at all.

What is the correct way to send the `function` to children using `spread` operators in reactjs?

Here is my code :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class Counter extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.props.display}</div>
        <button onClick={this.props.fun}>+</button> //onclick not works!!
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class CounterParent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0 //added
    };
  }

  increase = () => { //not called
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    });
  };

  render() {

    let object = {
      display: this.state.count,
      func: this.increase
    };

    return (
      <div >
        <Counter {...object} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<CounterParent />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Your `increase` function is passed in as `func`, but you try to use `this.props.fun` in your `Counter` component. Try `this.props.func` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In `Counter` component, you mispelled `func` name.

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.props.display}</div>
        <button onClick={this.props.func}>+</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what `super(props);` exactly do here? is it really required? ( see my code on question )

Comment: You need to call "super()" in order to use "this" in the constructor.

Comment: yes, if you define `constructor` func, it will be always required to call `super` func.